# Perl Fastcgi - HTTP::Message content must be bytes at

Tags: perl, unicode

I am getting the following errors:

> [Fri Feb 19 08:55:41 2016] [error] [client 172.16.30.100] FastCGI:
> server "/home/admin/soap/server.fcgi" stderr: HTTP::Message content
> must be bytes at
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/SOAP/Transport/HTTP.pm line 317
>
> [Fri Feb 19 08:55:41 2016] [error] [client 172.16.30.100] FastCGI:
> incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server
> "/home/admin/soap/server.fcgi" [Fri Feb 19 08:55:41 2016] [warn]
> FastCGI: server "/home/admin/soap/server.fcgi" (pid 45466) terminated
> by calling exit with status '255'

Here is line 317 of HTTP.pm  I appreciate any input on a fix.

```
$self->response(HTTP::Response->new(
$code => undef,
HTTP::Headers->new(
    'SOAPServer' => $self->product_tokens,
     $compressed ? (
         'Content-Encoding' => $COMPRESS) : (),
         'Content-Type' => join(
             '; ',
             'text/xml', 
             !$SOAP::Constants::DO_NOT_USE_CHARSET && $encoding ? 'charset=' . lc($encoding) : ()
         ),
         'Content-Length' => SOAP::Utils::bytelength $response),
     $response,
));
$self->response->headers->header('Content-Type' => 'Multipart/Related;       type="text/xml"; start="<main_envelope>"; boundary="'.$is_multipart.'"') if   $is_multipart; }
```

Comment: I have implemented Encode::encode.  So far so good.  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Error message is pretty much telling you all about it: content for `HTTP::Response` object that you provide with `$response` variable must be bytes - i.e. a buffer without any characters outside 0-255 range. Use [`Encode::encode`](http://p3rl.org/Encode#encode) to transform it from Perl internal representation to whatever encoding required for your protocol.

By the way, this has nothing to do with `fastcgi`. The first error cause the script to die without emitting a response, resulting in the second error message.